# Android Material Exposed Dropdown Menu activated use custom color instead of primary color

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am having issue trying to change the color of both the underline and floating label of my exposed drop down menu when it is activated. 
"colorControlActivated" of my filled exposed drop down menu is currently greenish blue.  regardless of what I indicate (black) in the style file, my registerOrderName menu will still use colorPrimary color for colorControlActivated. 
In my style file

```
    <!-- Legacy TextField Theme-->
    <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textPlaceholderColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/textFieldColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/textFieldColor</item>
    </style>

    <!-- TextField Hint Theme-->
    <style name="TextInputLayoutHintText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textPlaceholderColor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Legacy Drop Down Menu Theme-->
    <style name="MenuLayoutAppearance" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/textPlaceholderColor</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/textFieldColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/textFieldColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Autocomplete">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/textFieldColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/textFieldColor</item>
    </style>
```

in my activity.xml file

```
            android:id="@+id/registerTextInputLayout4"
            style="@style/MenuLayoutAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:elevation="12dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutHintText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/registerForm"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/registerForm"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerTextInputLayout3">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/registerOrderName"
                android:theme="@style/Autocomplete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:hint="@string/RegisterForm4"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/textFieldColor"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In my color file

```
    <color name="colorPrimary">#00BEBA</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00BEBA</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#F60606</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="green">#17B3AB</color>
    <color name="version">#0B0008</color>
    <color name="appBackgroundColor">#00BEBA</color>
    <color name="textPlaceholderColor">#807E7E</color>
    <color name="textFieldColor">#000000</color>
    <color name="textFieldCursorColor">#FB0000</color>
    <color name="textFieldHightLightColor">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="customGreen">#92CFCD</color>
    <color name="defaultLinkBlue">#007aff</color>
    <color name="facebookBlue">#3B5998</color>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `colorPrimary` using the `android:theme` attribute:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:theme="@style/InputText_Overlay"
        ..>

           <AutoCompleteTextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

with:

```
<style name="InputText_Overlay">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```